# Prioritizing different types of messages

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, scheduling

I have `t` different message types, that can arrive to queue `q` at a different time. Number of messages that arrive
at a particular time can vary. Every type has some priority.

I need to write an algorithm that will order this messages in priority queue with following rules:

- organize messages so higher priority of t is first message in queue.
- beside priority, we need also to take into consideration that messages of lower priority still need to show up in a queue at some percentage (e.g. every 10th message will be message with priority 2, and every 100th message will be with priority 3 etc.).
- if there are already messages with lower priority on head of the queue, higher priority should come before those on arrival
- if there are already messages with lower priority on head of the queue, and we do not receive more higher prior. messages - when taking from queue we take those with lower priority first

*Example1:*

- t1 - priority 1 (showing up 5 in 8)
- t2 - priority 2 (showing up 2 in 8)
- t3 - priority 3 (showing up 1 in 8)

Possible state of this queue (first 8 messages)

`q = t1,t1,t2,t1,t1,t2,t1,t3`

*Example2:*

after 5 `t2` messages arrive to an empty queue I have:

`q = t2,t2,t2,t2,t2`

now if there are 10 `t1` messages that arrive, I need following distribution:

`q = t1,t1,t2,t1,t1,t2,t1,t1,t2,t1,t1,t2,t1,t1,t2`

Is there already some algorithm that implements this functionality?

Comment: [Were the answers helpful?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is to keep three different queues for each priority. Maintain the count of number messages in each queue.

Let ratio1 = c1 / (c1 + c2 + c3). In your example, c1, c2, c3 are 5, 2, 1 respectively.

Pick (n1 * ratio1) messages from first queue, then pick (n2 * ratio2) messages from second queue, so on. n1, n2, n3 are number of messages currently in queue 1, 2, 3 respectively.

I explained my overall idea. You can extend this to any number of queues.

I thought of naming the above scheme as Priority based Round Robin algorithm. I searched for this name and I [found a relevant article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332546783_Priority_based_round_robin_PBRR_CPU_scheduling_algorithm)  as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. This was also my first thought. I also managed to implement same thing using one Priority queue for all priorities - when pushing to queue I just push according to priorities, but when polling from the queue - I have to update priority counters. Basically if I receive message for `t3`, I need to check if counter for `t1` and `t2` are lower than counter for `t3`, and increase those accordingly. The only problem I have here is that counters are increasing, so If queue is never empty I will get into Integer overflow. Not sure if there are some ways to solve this problem?

Comment: I could reset counters whenever queue is empty, or wait that I approach MAX_INTEGER and then pause adding to queue, until all the messages from queue are consumed. Just wanted to see if there are other possible approaches to solving this problem.

Comment: @BojanVukasovic We build upon the basic solution that I mentioned & need to tackle the scalability issues which you apparently need a separate post for. What to do when queue becomes full? Allocate more memory. If you are out of total available memory, need to go for distributed queues.

Comment: @BojanVukasovic: Additionally, no matter what the strategy is, you'll always have to think for scalability challenges if the volume of messages is high. That is why high volume high speed event/message streaming systems like Kafka, managed services like Azure Event Hubs, etc. exist.

Comment: @BojanVukasovic: You won't need to worry about integer overflow but memory overflow. You could use long, Big integers, etc.